# How to transfer a participant from a group call

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I would like to be able to use a Bot to transfer a Teams call participant to another Teams Identify/UserID endpoint.

This seems possible if there is only one party connected to the Bot, by using

`ICall.TransferAsync()`

[https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/calls/Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls.ICall.html#Microsoft_Graph_Communications_Calls_ICall_TransferAsync_Microsoft_Graph_InvitationParticipantInfo_System_Threading_CancellationToken_](http://%20https://microsoftgraph.github.io/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/docs/calls/Microsoft.Graph.Communications.Calls.ICall.html#Microsoft_Graph_Communications_Calls_ICall_TransferAsync_Microsoft_Graph_InvitationParticipantInfo_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

However, this does not work if there is more than one party in the call, as that API method does not identify the participant to transfer, only the call.

How can I initiate a transfer of a selected participant in a group call to a target Teams UserID ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Find a workaround. Like create new conversation invite the participant, on success cut him from the conference, or something like that.

You will need a lot of workarounds when working with Teams, until MS improved it further.